# Persistent selectList type mismatch ‘Database.Persist.Sql.Types.Internal.SqlBackend’

Tags: haskell, haskell-persistent

I am working on a Servant 0.7.1 application and trying to use Persistent-2.5 to query a Postgresql database, but I am getting mismatched types with a Persistent query.

This application was previously working with Servant 0.4 and Persistent 2.2, but when I went to Servant 0.7.1 in order to try out the BasicAuth stuff (different `stack` resolver, which is why I ended up with a higher version of `Persistent` too), I changed from `EitherT ServantErr IO` to Servant's `Handler` monad, and for some reason I could no longer get the Persistent query to compile.

Here's my model definition:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings] [persistLowerCase|
ESeries json
    label String
    name String Maybe
    relatedId ESeriesId Maybe
|]
```

Based on this [blog-post](http://www.parsonsmatt.org/2015/06/07/servant-persistent.html), I have a `runDb` function that looks like this, which will run inside a `ReaderT`:

```
runDb query = do
    pool <- asks getPool
    liftIO $ runSqlPool query pool
```

Finally, I have the following api definition and handler:

```
type ESeriesApi = "series" :> Get '[JSON] [ESeries]

eSeriesApi :: Proxy ESeriesApi
eSeriesApi = Proxy

type AppM = ReaderT Config Handler

readerToHandler :: Config -> AppM :~> Handler
readerToHandler cfg = Nat $ \x -> runReaderT x cfg

eServer :: Config -> Server ESeriesApi
eServer cfg = enter (readerToHandler cfg) eSeriesServer

app :: Config -> Application
app cfg = serve eSeriesApi (eServer cfg)

eSeriesServer :: ServerT ESeriesApi AppM
eSeriesServer = allSeries

allSeries :: AppM [ESeries]
allSeries = do
  series <- runDb $ selectList [] []
  let results = map (\(Entity _ e) -> e) series
  liftIO $ sequence results
```

I have tried many different variations on this, but it always comes down to the same error:

```
   • Couldn't match type ‘persistent-2.5:Database.Persist.Class.PersistEntity.PersistEntityBackend
                             (IO ESeries)’
                     with ‘Database.Persist.Sql.Types.Internal.SqlBackend’
        arising from a use of ‘selectList’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘selectList [] []’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: series <- runDb $ selectList [] []
      In the expression:
        do { series <- runDb $ selectList [] [];
             let results = map (\ (Entity _ e) -> ...) series;
             liftIO $ sequence results }
```

It seems that `selectList` is not returning the right type?

---

**Edit:**

I should have mentioned that I am trying to do this with Persistent 2.5 and this code previously worked with earlier versions of Persistent.

It looks like `runSqlPool` is expecting [`SqlPersistT`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2016-06-21/persistent-2.5/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v:runSqlPool) or `ReaderT SqlBackend` but `selectList` is returning `PersistEntityBackend (IO ESeries)`

Comment: It would helpful to see a compilable example. The signature of `selectList` has not changed from 2.2 to 2.5.

Comment: @ErikR, I copy-pasted code from a working project into a gist. It includes the depedency list at the bottom: https://gist.github.com/pellagic-puffbomb/931a06482942c0b9d608ec9ee4e664ad

Comment: here's where I'm at with your code: https://github.com/erantapaa/selectlist-question/tree/master - I'm getting an EitherT / ExceptT mismatch. Have a look and send me a PR.

Comment: @ErikR, sorry: had to go back to day job stuff. They switched from `EitherT` in previous versions of Servant to `ExceptT`. `Handler` is a type synonym for `ExceptT ServantErr IO`: http://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Server.html#the-handler-monad I'll try to give your version a shot. Looks like my issue my be related to this: https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/286